# loading image in swiftUI causing nil while unwrapping

Tags: swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm getting the following error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In my `ProfileView()` im using `import URLImage` library.

```
                URLImage(URL(string: self.profileViewModel.profileURL)!, placeholder: Image(systemName: "circle"),
                     content:  {
                        $0.image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .overlay(
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                ,alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.profileViewModel.showImagePicker = true
                            }
                        }
            )
```

In my `ProfileView()` im using `.onAppear(perform: loadUserData)`

This works good, brings back the correct data for the user and displays it as expected.

```
 func LoadAUser(userId: String) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId).getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
        guard let snap = snapshot else {
            print("error fetching data")
            return
        }
        let dict = snap.data()
        guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict!) else { return }
        print("decoded user - load user - \(decodedUser)")
        self.bio = decodedUser.bio
        self.occupation = decodedUser.occupation
        self.city = decodedUser.city
        self.profileURL = decodedUser.profileURL

        let storageRoot = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://myapp.appspot.com").child("avatar").child(userId)

        storageRoot.downloadURL{(url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let profileDownload = url?.absoluteString
            self.profileURL = profileDownload!
        }

        print("profileURL - \(self.profileURL)")
    }
}
```

The storage has an image and i can retrieve it as the log shows `print("profileURL - \(self.profileURL)")` everything is good here

I just can't seem to display the profile image in the `ProfileView()`

the function is called in the profile view like so in .onAppear

```
func loadUserData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        self.profileViewModel.LoadAUser(userId: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
    }
}
```

I had tried adding a delay:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10)
```

Just the image won't load and im not sure why it says `found nil` when every thing else is loaded but when I add this URLImage to bring the image back it says nil, even tho the log says it has the correct URL.

**UPDATE**

I have a `class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject`

Which has

```
@Published var profileURL: String = ""
```

In loadAUser function. I set it:

```
self.profileURL = profileDownload!
```

Comment: do this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and we can help you, else we can just guess....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around, I got the value from the sessionStore

```
URLImage(URL(string: self.session.userInSession!.profileURL)!,
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an error inside your posted code, but there are some things which you didn't post about your class:

You seem to have class (the profileViewModel) in which you have to save your image to a variable which was at the top of your class declared like this: `@Published var image ...`

If you say you are able to retrieve all the data you need (including the image) with `.onAppear(perform: loadUserData)` then you just have to save your image to the variable after fetching it inside your ViewModel and alle Views with access to the `@ObservedObject profileViewModel` have access to `profileViewModel.image`.